# iOS Won't pass variable to child view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have faced a problem I can not see the problem to. I am trying to pass a simple `NSString` to a child variable but it continues to return as `null` even when I use `NSLog` to show there is a string in the variable.

The variable `finalDate` will not pass to the child view.

**Parent View**

```
ChangeTimeViewController *ChangeTimeView = [[ChangeTimeViewController alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
ChangeTimeView.finalDate = date;
[ChangeTimeView setDelegate:self];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ChangeTimeView animated:YES];
```

**Child View .H**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ChangeTimeViewControllerDelegate;

@interface ChangeTimeViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <ChangeTimeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *enteredTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPickerView *UIPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *finalDate;

@end

@protocol ChangeTimeViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)childTimeViewController:(ChangeTimeViewController *)viewController didChooseValue:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

**Child View .M**

```
NSLog(@"%@", self->finalDate);
```

Comment: can I know in which method you put your log

Comment: One point. Your variable name `date` and `finalDate` are very confusing as they are instances of `NSString` not `NSDate`. Same with `enteredTime`. Your variable names should tell me as much info as possible about them. (Also, don't use upper case letters for the tart of variable names "UIPicker" should be something like "myDatePicker" or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is perfectly fine. You should insert the NSLog in the `view(Did/Will)Appear` or some similar method and you may use the `self.finalDate` notation to make sure you don't try to read some uninitialized ivar.

Note: properties synthesize ivars with `_` as prefix (_finalDate is the correct storage unless you synthesized it it with some other name)

If you want to make sure that all input parameters are passed to the view controller, then create an `init` method for it. Similar to this:

```
- (id)initWithDate:(NSDate*)date delegate:(id)delegate
```

Comment: That is not working, even with a test string for final date like `ChangeTimeView.finalDate = @"TEST";` then using either `NSLog(@"%@", finalDate);`, `NSLog(@"%@", _finalDate);`, and `NSLog(@"%@", self.finalDate);` all return as `null`

Answer (score 0):

Pass `NSString` As `ChangeTimeView.finalDate = @"This Is my Simple String";` and use/put  `NSLog` in `viewDidLoad` method for show is it rich at nextViewController or not ?? Otherwise if your **date** (`NSString`) is proper then Your code is correct.

Comment: have you got any warning message ??? if yes then temporary remove your PROTOCOL declaration.. and check it.

Answer (score 0):

Check what is happening if you set like,

```
ChangeTimeView.finalDate = @"MyString";
```

and in view.m log `NSLog(@"%@", self.finalDate);`

Comment: Still is not working, view comment about. Returns as `null` still.